# How to implement swapping of structs for the insertion sorting algorithm in C

Tags: c, struct, insertion-sort

I have a working insertion sort algorithm that sorts integers stored in an array.  In a different program I have created a struct with words and a count.  I need to sort structs stored in an array alphabetically using the same insertion sort.  I understand how to compare them, however I cannot find a way to swap them.  Ideas?

```
typedef struct { char * word; int count; } wordType;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can swap `struct`s the same way that you swap integers:

```
wordType tmp;
wordType a = {.word="hello", .count=5};
wordType b = {.word="world", .count=11};
tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/4pjHPR).

Answer (score 2):

How to swap them? Just use a temporary structure:

```
void swapEm (wordType *w1, wordType *w2) {
    wordType wx;

    memcpy (&wx, w1,  sizeof(wx));
    memcpy (w1,  w2,  sizeof(wx));
    memcpy (w2,  &wx, sizeof(wx));
}
```

See the following complete program for an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct { char * word; int count; } wordType;

void swapEm (wordType *w1, wordType *w2) {
    wordType wx;

    memcpy (&wx, w1,  sizeof(wx));
    memcpy (w1,  w2,  sizeof(wx));
    memcpy (w2,  &wx, sizeof(wx));
}

void printOne (char *s, wordType *w) {
    printf ("%s: %d [%s]\n", s, w->count, w->word);
}

int main(void) {
    wordType w1, w2;
    w1.word = strdup ("from Pax."); w1.count = 314159;
    w2.word = strdup ("Hello");     w2.count = 271828;

    printOne ("w1", &w1); printOne ("w2", &w2);
    swapEm (&w1, &w2);
    puts ("===");
    printOne ("w1", &w1); printOne ("w2", &w2);

    free (w1.word); free (w2.word);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
w1: 314159 [from Pax.]
w2: 271828 [Hello]
===
w1: 271828 [Hello]
w2: 314159 [from Pax.]
```

Comment: Just be careful with that string.

Comment: The string is fine, it's just a pointer and will be swapped as-is. Since you're _swapping_ the two items in totality, it makes no difference whether it's a shallow or deep copy.

Comment: Yeah it'd mostly be fine. Just be careful of any other references to the strings lying around. Something like: `char *s1 = w1.word; swapEm(&w1, &w2); strcpy(s1, "You're w1");` Oops, wrote to the wrong string. Admittedly, this kind of thing is unlikely to happen in an Insertion sort, and whether or not doing this is actually an error depends on the intention behind the swap in the first place. Just be careful.